# mailutils in script versus command line

Tags: bash, mail, mailutils

The following works fine as expected from command line:

```
mail < /home/incoming/mailprocoutput.txt -s "Message Processing results..." -r from@somewhere.com someusername@gmail.com
```

cat filename pipe mail etc also works fine on command line.  But either method results in an empty message body when used in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is to send an email from the mailproc python script with the results of message processing

timestamp=$( date +%T )
curDate=$( date +"%m-%d-%y" )

logger "Mailproc has run at $timestamp on $curDate, sending response back to the creator..."

mail < /home/incoming/mailprocoutput.txt -s "Message Processing results..." -r from@somewhere.com someusername@gmail.com

exit
```

What am I doing wrong?  Ubuntu 18.04, GNU mailutils version 3.4

Comment: Are the command line and the script being run from *the same user*? Do you get any _stderr_ output from the script?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Are you running the script at system startup, via `cron`, `at`, or `batch`? Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Comment: @FedKad apparently it is indeed a user issue.  The script runs under user incoming and indeed the command line cat-to-pipe-to-mail does not work for that user, but works for root.  So I have a user rights issue.

Comment: su username then attempt to cat file and I get nothing.  the file is 0644 username:username
So is there something I have to do to allow the user to have rights to cat something which is shown as owned by that user?  Befuddled, I am.

Comment: I would redirect the `stderr` output _of the whole script_ to some writable location like `2>/tmp/mymail.err` to see what the error is.